# Logging Identifiers across methods

Tags: java, logback

I have some ids (id from database, example 34645) that I currently log as "[34645] - something happended" using something like:

```
log.info("[" + id + "]" + foo);
```

Some logs, like "server starting", "database connection bla" dont have an id and thus doesn't log any and that's fine.

However, when I have an id I call methods that also log, but don't have the id, like:

```
lookup(name) {
  //do some lookup and stuff
  log.info("[" + name + "]" has some info we use somewhere: " + result);
}
```

Is there a (smart) way to get the id logged inside lookup() without passing id to lookup() or refactor class hierarchies? There are different threads logging so setting/unsetting id-values for logback to use will probably be difficult to get right.

Comment: Hey, could it be you are looking for MDC: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html Depending on what you use for logging, the MDC let's you set a log context per thread. So if you have an ID, you can easily set it in the MDC and then you don't even have to explicitly log your ID.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.

Comment: That was great, can you post some kind of answer so you get some credit? :)

Comment: Thanks :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per request and I like credits, you can use MDC for that thing.

Info on that is here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Thanks :)